File comparison - File 1 have DOB, File 2 have range for it
My requirement is as follows:

File 1 has records 1,10,ch in date (CCYY-MM-DD) (millions of records)
File 2 has 1 record with data 2006-11-17 2006-12-26 2007-01-16

I need to compare all records of File 1 with values in File 2.
I have done as following so far, but records are not coming as expected.
Below is my JCL.
//PAS00070 EXEC PGM=SORT                                               
//SORTJNF1 DD DSN=DOB.FILE,                
//         DISP=SHR                                                    
//SORTJNF2 DD DSN=DOB.COMPARE.VALUE,                
//         DISP=SHR                                                    
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=DOB.RESULT,               
//            DISP=(,CATLG,CATLG),                                     
//            SPACE=(CYL,(4500,500),RLSE),                             
//            LRECL=71,RECFM=FB                                        
//SYSIN    DD *                                                        
  JOINKEYS FILES=F1,FIELDS=(1,5,A)                                     
  JOINKEYS FILES=F2,FIELDS=(1,5,A)                                     
  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,F2                                                  
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,70,F2:1,30)                                    
  INCLUDE COND=(5,10,CH,GE,21,10,CH,AND,                               
         5,10,CH,LE,1,10,CH)                                           
  OUTREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(5,10,CH,GE,21,10,CH,AND, 
         5,10,CH,LE,1,10,CH,AND,                     
         5,10,CH,EQ,11,10,CH),                          
         BUILD=(1,70,C'B')),                                           
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(5,10,CH,GE,21,10,CH,AND,
         5,10,CH,LE,1,10,CH,AND,  
         5,10,CH,GT,11,10,CH),                                         
         BUILD=(1,70,C'C')),                                           
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(5,10,CH,GE,21,10,CH,AND,
         5,10,CH,LE,1,10,CH,AND,  
         5,10,CH,LT,11,10,CH),                                         
         BUILD=(1,70,C'A'))                                            
  SORT FIELDS=(1,4,BI,A)                                               
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SYSABEND DD SYSOUT=*   

                                          

